# Select Multiple Values from Same Column; one sql statment

Tags: mysql, select

I am looking to return a list of users from a database. There are hundreds of users in the db. Each user has it's own unique user_id. All of the values that I am trying to return reside in the same column (meta_value).

The database structure is as follows:

```
id | user_id | meta_key | meta_value
```

sample data is as follows:

```
1 | 3434 | first_name | Brandon
2 | 3434 | last_name  | Johnson
3 | 3434 | street_add | 123 main
4 | 3434 | city       | ocean beach
5 | 3434 | state      | Texas
```

I am trying to return the first name, last name, street_add, city, and state in one sql statement.

I'd like the output to look like:

```
Brandon, Johnson, 123 Main, Ocean Beach, Texas
```

Comment: Do all user_ids respect the same order,first comes firstname than lastname and so on,ordered by id?You could use `SELECT user_id,GROUP_CONCAT(meta_value ORDER BY id) FROM t GROUP BY user_id`

Comment: When you say "one query" do you mean "one row?"  An example of your expected output would be helpful.

Comment: Michael Green - I am just looking to pull all the records in a single sql statement. I updated the post to show the desired output. I'd like to pull all the user's info from the database in the output like above to export to an excel sheet

Comment: Mihai - There are more records in the meta_value column than just first name, last name, address, city, state and zip. However, those are the only records I am looking to pull.

Comment: `SELECT user_id,GROUP_CONCAT(meta_value ORDER BY id) FROM t WHERE meta_key  IN('first_name','last_name',etc) GROUP BY user_id`

Comment: @Mihai - Thank you very much! That worked perfectly. If you put as answer, I will approve it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just use GROUP_CONCAT with a WHERE condition

```
SELECT user_id,GROUP_CONCAT(meta_value ORDER BY id) 
FROM t 
WHERE meta_key  IN('first_name','last_name','street_add','city','state') 
GROUP BY user_id
```