# Select Multiple Values from Same Column; one sql statement and split into separate columns

Tags: mysql, pivot

This post derives from following - 
[Select Multiple Values from Same Column; one sql statment](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/77997/select-multiple-values-from-same-column-one-sql-statment/101952#101952)

Based on this query -

```
 SELECT user_id,GROUP_CONCAT(meta_value ORDER BY id) 
 FROM t 
 WHERE meta_key  IN('first_name','last_name','street_add','city','state') 
 GROUP BY user_id
```

It will give me a comma separated column, which is great and gives me the data, but is there a way to separate the fields into columns?

Comment: Do you want a pivot?

Comment: The data i get is - 
ID    | num1,num2,num3

I need num1,num2,num3 in separate columns.

Comment: Just to be clear, are you looking to alter the table by adding columns, or are you just trying to split the results of the above select query?

Comment: Adding Columns is what im after.

Answer (score 1):

The way you are describing the expected result; I am concerned that what you are looking for won't get you what you want. Taking the example from the referenced post, you may actually want:

```
create view yourview1 as (
  select
    user_id,
    case when Item_Type = "first_name" then meta_value end as first_name,
    case when Item_Type = "last_name" then meta_value end as last_name,
    case when Item_Type = "street_add" then meta_value end as street_add,
    case when Item_Type = "city" then meta_value end as city,
    case when Item_Type = "state" then meta_value end as state
  from User_Items
); 

create view yourview1_Pivot as (
  select
    user_id,
    MAX(first_name) as first_name,
    MAX(last_name) as last_name,
    MAX(street_add) as street_add,
    MAX(city) as city,
    MAX(state) as state 
  from yourview1
  group by user_id
);
```

[source](http://stratosprovatopoulos.com/web-development/mysql/pivot-a-table-in-mysql/)

Comment: Why the `MAX()`?  Seems like you would get a mess.

Comment: The MAX() is due to the grouping and the necessity of an aggregate. As long as the ids are unique, it shouldn't cause a "mess" in this particular case.

Comment: You can have a `GROUP BY` without any aggregate functions.  It's pretty sloppy of the `VIEW` to be returning duplicate rows.

Comment: After researching and running across this (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-handling.html), I agree with you and will edit my answer. Thanks for educating me.

Comment: It was a disservice on @RickJames's part to talk you out of using MAX(). The fact that you can reference non-GROUP BY columns without aggregation in MySQL doesn't mean you should. MAX() is important in this particular case. Otherwise your second view [will always be returning just nulls](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6221f5/2) in all columns (other than `user_id`) except one or sometimes without an exception.

Comment: And, by the way, you don't really need two views for this, because you can do CASE and MAX in one go: `max(case when Item_Type = "first_name" then meta_value end) as first_name`.

Comment: @AndriyM you should answer and get the glory(and corresponding points)! :D

Comment: Thanks, I probably will because I can't find a generic MySQL Pivot question to flag this one as a duplicate. But please consider rolling back your answer to the original revision too.

Comment: Done and done. I liked it better the first way anyway. Feel free to upvote my original smartypantsyness.

Answer (score 1):

You essentially want to pivot the `meta_value` column. Some SQL products have dedicated syntax for this operation. MySQL does not have it, but there is a universal method that works in most products, including MySQL: conditional aggregation.

```
SELECT
  user_id,
  MAX(CASE meta_key WHEN 'first_name' THEN meta_value END)  AS first_name,
  MAX(CASE meta_key WHEN 'last_name'  THEN meta_value END)  AS last_name,
  MAX(CASE meta_key WHEN 'street_add' THEN meta_value END)  AS street_add,
  MAX(CASE meta_key WHEN 'city'       THEN meta_value END)  AS city,
  MAX(CASE meta_key WHEN 'state'      THEN meta_value END)  AS state
FROM
  t
WHERE
  meta_key IN ('first_name','last_name','street_add','city','state')
GROUP BY
  user_id
;
```

Fundamentally, this is the same approach as the one [suggested by SQLHound](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/102061/6965), except, in my opinion, there is no need to create a view specifically to solve this problem. (Although it may make sense to create a view for a particular set of pivoted columns if that information is requested often or used in many other queries – makes those queries simpler and more maintainable.) Also, as you can see, pivoting can be done as a single step operation – no need to derive a set of CASEs first and only then aggregate them.